# Using Google Cloud Storage JSON Api (React-Native and Cloud Functions)

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-storage

Currently, my app calls google cloud storage from the client-side and that causes us to store a lot of sensitive information on the client-side. For the past three days, I've been trying to figure out how to use google cloud JSON API to no avail. Can anyone walk through the process from beginning to end of setting that up and uploading images to google cloud storage from the server-side using node.JS

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your IAM permissions are set up - otherwise your app will crash when trying to use cloud storage. I've attached a link to an open source github as well that will walk you through setting this up. It is called google-cloud-nodejs-client in case the link moves.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys
https://github.com/aslamanver/google-cloud-nodejs-client